# Best algorithm for motion detection?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision

I wonder what is the best algorithm for motion detection of human subjects. Keeping in mind that the motion is detected for moving objects with tolerance of leaving out minor changes to the environment. Matlab/OpenCV sources would be great!

Thanks

Comment: This ends up being rather underspecified. Sure it's for "human subjects", but you have not told us what kinds of uses you intend and if motion will be the norm or the exception, not what metric you're using for "good".  Do you need to optimize for CPU usage, for storage, for minimized false positives for minimized false negatives, etc, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time back i saw this page, where you can see the code of the thesis and the thesis of *"A real-world system for human motion detection and tracking"* maybe this can help you.

[Thesis David Moore](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/~dmoore/)

This could to be a good point to begin.

Comment: Thanks mate, will have a look at it.

Comment: don't worry i hope help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
[www.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/Publis/icvgip04.pdf](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/Publis/icvgip04.pdf)